# Find $f(a,b)$ given $f(a,1)$, $f(a,2)$, ...

Tags: systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations, interpolation

I have a bivariate function $f(a,b)$ that takes 2 positive integers as input and gives another as output. I do not know the "inner-workings" of the function — I can only see the value it returns when I give it any 2 variables. I would like to represent this function with an equation.

My naive attempt at this:

1. I call the function repeatedly with a different value for $a$ each time while $b$ is fixed at 1. This gives me a sequence of output integers.
2. I ask Wolfram|Alpha to interpolate a function from this sequence and it gives me a univariate polynomial function: $g(a) = \text{some polynomial}$. I seem to always get an exact function that gives the correct output for any value of $a$. This tells me that $f(a,1) = \text{some polynomial}$.
3. Next, I repeat steps 1 and 2, incrementing $b$ by 1 each time to get several more such functions: $f(a,2) = \text{polynomial 2}$, $f(a,3) = \text{polynomial 3}$, etc.

This gives me a system of univariate functions which represent the output of my bivariate function for any $a$ and $b$. How can I use these to get a single simplified function for $f(a,b)$?

#### Example

Let's say I know the following:

1. $f(a,1) = 1$
2. $f(a,2) = 2a + 1$
3. $f(a,3) = 3a^2 + 3a + 1$
4. $f(a,4) = 4a^3 + 6a^2 + 4a + 1$

For this simple example, the values of each of these functions shows up as a sequence in the OEIS which helps to discover that $f(a,b) = (a + 1)^b - a^b$.

However, not all sets of functions are this simple where each function is in the OEIS. Is there a standard way to find $f(a,b)$ given $f(a,1)$, $f(a,2)$, etc.?

Comment: Perhaps related?: [Find the generating function for a series , given a recurrence relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/755151/find-the-generating-function-for-a-series-given-a-recurrence-relation)

Comment: As a counterexample, what prevents $f$ from being a piecewise function where $f(n,m) = 0$ for some $n,m \in \Bbb Z$ and $f(a,m) = g(a)$ for all other $a$?

Comment: @PhillipHamilton The last ordered list in my question is basically just another way of writing the piecewise function. My goal is to unpiecewise a piecewise function. :)

Comment: That's not inherently possible.  A piecewise function with a discontinuity, as an example, cannot be "unpiecewised" into a continuous form.  If your goal is to get the statistically closest continuous polynomial form, that is a much different question.

Comment: Can it not be unpiecwised into a diophantine (only integer solutions) function?

Comment: Ah wait this is a stats question, isn't it. Is that what you mean by interpolate?

Comment: It can be represented as such, but not perfectly or with no error.

Comment: Yes, my application is not stats though, so I didn't realize it was stats related until looking deeper. It seems like what I'm wanting may be what's called [global polynomial interpolation](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geostatistical-analyst/how-global-polynomial-interpolation-works.htm). But I've not really got a clue how to try this method.

Comment: Because my application is not stats, there is no error in known values and I believe (at least every piece of) the piecewise function has an exact representation as a polynomial.

Comment: Similar question: [Developing a function of two variables from given data](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1029399/developing-a-function-of-two-variables-from-given-data?rq=1)

Comment: Also relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_interpolation

Answer (score 1):

Without sampling every integer for $a$ and $b$ in the domain of $f(a,b)$, you cannot be certain that you have the correct polynomial. That said, you can construct a polynomial to exactly fit an arbitrary number of your sampled function values. This can be done with Lagrange polynomials.

For $n^2$ sample points $(a_i,b_j)$ with function values $f_{ij}$, the polynomial is given by

$$f(a,b)=\sum_i^n\sum_j^nf_{ij}\prod_{r\neq i}^{n}\frac{a-a_r}{a_i-a_r}\prod_{s\neq j}^{n}\frac{b-b_s}{b_j-b_s}$$

You can see that gives the correct value for any of your sample points by substitution into the equation. For example, if I solve $f(a_4,b_5)$, only the $i = 4, j = 5$ term is nontrivial because all others will either have a $a_4 - a_4$ or $b_5 - b_5$ term in the numerator of the product. The products evaluate to 1 and you are left with $f_{4~5}$ as desired.

By plugging in a value for $b$, you are left with a polynomial in $a$.

I extended the definition of the Lagrange polynomial to the two dimensional case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial

Comment: Thanks Matthew. Is it possible to evaluate something like that online? What does the $r \neq i$ mean? How does that give a starting value for the variable $r$ to progress from?

Comment: In the sums, $i$ and $j$ start as 1 and run to n. In the products, $r$ and $s$ start as 1 and run to n, but if $r=i$ or $s=j$ the term is skipped. This polynomial is not the only one that would give the proper values for the sample points. You could use Mathematica or something similar to write a program that would calculate the polynomial and simplify the expression. It would be interesting to see if the polynomial doesn't change after a certain amount of sample points are used. This method won't be able to converge to your exponential example for finitely many points.

Answer (score 0):

If we consider the sequence of functions $f_m (a) = f(a,m) \in \Bbb N$ for all $a \in \Bbb N$, $m = 0,1,2,...$, we cannot generally say if this sequence converges to some $f$. It may diverge at some $a$, converge pointwise elsewhere.  There's not even a guarantee that for $a_1, a_2 \in \Bbb N$ where the sequence of functions does converge that $\lim_{m \to \infty} f_m (a_1) = \lim_{m \to \infty} f_m (a_2)$.  We could have pointwise convergence to different functions.

But your assumption is that such an $f(a,b)$ does exist, always for all $a,b \in \Bbb N$.  Even further you are making a much stronger assumption that $f_1(a) = f_2(a) = ... = f(a,b)$ (per your comments about "unpiecewising" the function, finding exactly one such $f$ that holds for all $a,b$). In general as a question about sequences of functions this is not true.

Comment: As a follow up, I would read up on Sequences of Functions. I am taking your question somewhat literally - as an example I've completely ignored the interpolate tag because your question isn't really about that. But if your real question is about finding the best statistical fit for a surface I would rework the question.